# Edit Update not working on MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm new to MS Access. This is a basic stuff. I'm doing an edit button in MS Access forms, but I keep getting runtime errors. Here it is the code:

```vb
CurrentDb.Execute " UPDATE FLIGHT SET " & _
"STD= ' " & Me.Text3 & " ' " & _
",Destination = ' " & Me.Text5 & " ' " & _
",Remark = ' " & Me.Text7 & " ' " & _
",ETD = ' " & Me.Text9 & " ' " & _
",ATD = ' " & Me.Text11 & " ' " & _
",OFBL =  ' " & Me.Text13 & " ' " & _
",CAR= ' " & Me.Text15 & " '  " & _
",Nature = ' " & Me.Text17 & " ' " & _
",REG_N0 = ' " & Me.Text19 & " ' " & _
"WHERE FLIGHT_NR = " & Me.Text0

flightsubform.Form.Requery
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: Run-time error '3075'

Comment: Syntax error in query expression 'FLIGHT_NR=(first value)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the Field FLIGHT_NR a integer field (1,145) or a text field (KQ145)?

If its a integer field you might need to change your Where statement to capture Me.Text0 as an integer as below:

```
" WHERE FLIGHT_NR = " & int(Me.Text0)
```

If its a text field you might need to add quotes around your Me.Text0 value to capture it as text:

```
" WHERE FLIGHT_NR = " & " ' " & Me.Text0 & " ' "
```

**Edit:**
Change your code for debugging as follows:

```
My_SqlText =  " UPDATE FLIGHT SET " & _
"STD= ' " & Me.Text3 & " ' " & _
",Destination = ' " & Me.Text5 & " ' " & _
",Remark = ' " & Me.Text7 & " ' " & _
",ETD = ' " & Me.Text9 & " ' " & _
",ATD = ' " & Me.Text11 & " ' " & _
",OFBL =  ' " & Me.Text13 & " ' " & _
",CAR= ' " & Me.Text15 & " '  " & _
",Nature = ' " & Me.Text17 & " ' " & _
",REG_N0 = ' " & Me.Text19 & " ' " & _
" WHERE FLIGHT_NR = " & " ' " & Me.Text0 & " ' "
Debug.print My_SqlText 'Will print it to immediate window for inspection
CurrentDb.Execute My_SqlText 
 UPDATE FLIGHT SET STD= ' 4:55:00 PM ' ,Destination = ' ATH ' ,Remark = ' DEP ' ,ETD = '  ' ,ATD = ' 5:15:00 PM ' ,OFBL =  ' 5:05:00 PM ' ,CAR= ' A3 '  ,Nature = ' J ' ,REG_N0 = ' ZA_A309 '  WHERE FLIGHT_NR =  ' A3 847 ' 





 UPDATE FLIGHT SET STD= ' 4:55:00 PM ' ,Destination = ' ATH ' ,Remark = ' DEP ' ,ETD = '  ' ,ATD = ' 5:15:00 PM ' ,OFBL =  ' 5:05:00 PM ' ,CAR= ' A3 '  ,Nature = ' J ' ,REG_N0 = ' ZA_A309 '  WHERE FLIGHT_NR =  ' A3 847 '
```

Comment: thanks @avagut .. its text but now its runtime error 3601.Too few parameters. :/

Comment: Hmm, usually that means there is a field that is not receiving a value to update. May I suggest viewing the statement in the Immediate window before running? While you are in the VBA Code Editor, Press Crtl+G, the Immediate Window pops up at the bottom. See my updated answer and check if the statement being executed has all the correct values.

Comment: i posted  them but these are  values of my table i want to update them,to change them

Comment: Should the field ETD be empty as its showing in the debug ETD = '  ' ?

Comment: Yeap it suppossed to be empty sometimes

Comment: Please check if the field ETD in Table Design View has the property Allow Zero Length Set to Yes. Also, I see some of the fields are time fields (STD= ' 4:55:00 PM ') is the corresponding column in the table a date/time column? If yes, you will need to add in your code a # chararcter before and after any date/time values eg " STD= #" & Me.Text3 & "# "

Comment: im new in stackoverflow and it seem that  it doesnt have a direct message options.. maybe send you the  db so you can check it by yourself! but thanks a lot for your help man.

Comment: Hi Ardit, I have picked the debug output and loaded into the SQL view of a query. It immediately threw an error that the Update statement is trying to update a field called REG_N0 ie the last character is a zero. The table has column called REG_No the last character is a letter o. Please change your VBA code to show the correct column. REG_No

Comment: I also notice you have spaces in your code between the quotes and the textbox values. If you try to update ' AZ 511 '  it wont find any such flight. You need to remove the extra spaces to make it 'AZ 511' which is what is in the table

Comment: thanks a lot man it does now but how can i change the code to update FLIGHT_NR which is primary key?

Comment: Why would want to change the FLIGHT_NR? You would then be refering to another Flight yes? Therefore you would be looking to add a new row of data instead of updating an earlier one